# Reduce logical reads when a certain condition is not available

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a three-tier system.

- A tracking / monitoring db (this is in MSSQL)
- A web service as a wrapper to communicate with this db
- A widows service which performs the actual operation

The windows service usually sends request to the web service once every minute to see if it has anything to process.

The process is triggered if there is any record in the tracking db with **Status** as **CREATED**.

The Status column has four possible values

- REQUESTED
- CREATED
- FAILED
- COMPLETED

I created an index for this Status column with the necessary details in the INCLUDE list and that works fine when there is a record with Status as CREATED.

But, when there is no record with Status as Created, then it leads to lots of logical reads in that table.

Are there any suggestions for reducing the number of logical reads when there is no record with Status as CREATED ?

Comment: Check the execution plan to verify the index is being used as expected.  I would expect a small number of logical reads if the query plan shows the index being used as expected.  It may help if you provide the `CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE INDEX` and query.  In any case, consider a filtered index WHERE `Status = 'CREATED'`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like when there are very few records, the statistics histogram knows exactly how many records exist in that range. When there are zero records and the statistics are up to date, the histogram shows character ranges, not exact values, and uses average distribution of the values that do exist to guess what the distribution is for the supplied value, and the average distribution of the other values in that table are probably very large. I would be interested to see how this would react if you changed your table definition to use an int for the status that is then fk'd to a lookup table for the status instead of having a varchar column in the table directly. I have a suspicion that the histogram for int's is going to work better for you than varchar. The other option which I'm fairly sure would work would be to use an "if/else" based on a row count against the table, which would be fed directly off of the index, and in the "else" block, when there are no rows, "select top 0..." so it still returns the correct schema but does no actual work.